# Continuous function space from compact metric space to separable Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $(M,\rho)$ is a compact metric space and $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ is a separable Banach space. Define
$$
C(M,X):=\{f:M\to X\ | f \text{ is continuous}\}.
$$
and
$$
\|f\|:=\max_{x\in M}\|f(x)\|_X.
$$
It is easy for me to verify that $C(M,X)$ is a Banach space, but my question is whether $C(M,X)$ is separable?

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way to prove it is to consider the space $B(M,X)$ of bounded functions with the same norm. Then $C(M,X)$ is a subspace. Since we deal with metric spaces, it sufficies to find a countable set $F$ of functions from $B(M,X)$ such that $C(M,X)\subset \overline F$.

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ one can consider the open cover $\{B(x,1/n):x\in M\}$ of the compact space $M$. It has a finite subcover $\{C^n_i:1\leq i\leq k_n\}$. We can make this family disjoint this way:
$$ D^n_i = C^n_i\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}C^n_j.$$ We got
$$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k_n}D_i^n\ \text{ (disjoint sum) and }\mathrm{diam}(D_i^n)\leq \frac 2n.$$

If $\{x_1,x_2\ldots\}$ is a dense subset of $X$ then for any $s\in \Bbb N^{k_n}$ we consider the function
$$f_{n,s}(x)= x_{s_i}\text{ for }x\in D^n_i,\ 1\leq i\leq k_n.$$
Now the set $F=\{f_{n,s}:n\in\Bbb N,\ s\in \Bbb N^{k_n}\}$ is the desired dense set.

To prove it consider any function $g\in C(M,X)$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$. Let $\delta>0$ be from the uniform continuity of $g$. Take $n$ so small that $2/n<\delta$. For each $1\leq i\leq k_n$ choose any point $m_i\in D^n_i$ (WLOG we can assume that these sets are nonempty) and find $q_i$ such that $\|x_{q_i}-g(m_i)\|<\varepsilon$. The function
$$f(x) = x_{q_i}\text{ for }x\in D^n_i,\ 1\leq i\leq k_n$$ belongs to $F$ and for $x\in D^n_i$ we have $x,m_i\in D^n_i$, so $d(x,m_i)<\delta$ and therefore
$$\|f(x)-g(x)\| =  \|x_{q_i}-g(x)\|\leq \|x_{q_i}-g(m_i)\|+\|g(m_i)-g(x)\|<\varepsilon + \varepsilon = 2\varepsilon.$$

Since the estimate goes for all $x\in X$ we have $\|f-g\|<2\varepsilon$. Since for any $g\in C(M,X)$ we can find an element $f\in F$ that is arbitrarily close to $g$ we get that $C(M,X)\subset \overline F$.

Of course $F$ is countable.

Comment: Thanks! But I still want to know your $B(M,X)$ is the space of function $f$ with $\max_{x\in M}\|f(x)\|_X<\infty$ or $\sup_{x\in M}\|f(x)\|_X<\infty$?

Comment: Thanks again. My initial ideal is to use partition of unity to construct a family of continuous functions, but I failed. I think your answer help me a lot.

Comment: Test, it's much easier to create discontinuous functions lying outside our spacer. Fortunatelly we've got the space B(M,X).